# Cplex data element has already set

Tags: python, database, optimization, cplex, opl

my Cplex model has this error in data section "data element has already set" but its not set, maybe i could not import data correctly, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRK1.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your .mod you have not written =...; but = with a value or with a semi-colon.

.mod

```
int a;
```

.dat

```
a=2;
```

gives the same error but if you change

```
int a;
```

into

```
int a=...;
```

then it's fine

Comment: in my model i defined indexes like this:

int s=...;
int i=...;
int p=...;
int m=...;
int t=...;

Comment: so i think in data file i should quantification indexes like this:
s= 3;
i= 9;
p= 5;
t= 4;
m=4;